# Mapped grid color for pgfplots colorbar

Tags: pgfplots, color, grids

I am trying to use a variation of the mapped color for a prepared contour plot.  The line color is correctly adjusted using `draw color=mapped color!50!black`, but I am unable to use the mapped color value for the grid of the colorbar.  The example below produces black gridlines, but I would like them to be a darker shade of the color corresponding to the tick value.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.11}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[colorbar,colorbar style={grid,grid style={color=mapped color!50!black}}]
        \addplot[contour prepared,contour/draw color=mapped color!50!black]
            table {
                2 2 0.8
                0.857143 2 0.6
                1 1 0.6
                2 0.857143 0.6
                2.5 1 0.6
                2.66667 2 0.6
                0.571429 2 0.4
                0.666667 1 0.4
                1 0.666667 0.4
                2 0.571429 0.4
                3 0.8 0.4
                0.285714 2 0.2
                0.333333 1 0.2
                1 0.333333 0.2
                2 0.285714 0.2
                3 0.4 0.2
            };
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A grid will always have the same color, changing its colors depending on the current value is unsupported. But there is a different way.

My idea is that we could draw *two* colorbars on top of each other: one with the shading (i.e. yours as-is) and one with `colorbar sampled line` and a bar marker. The key idea is to modify `colorbar/draw`, a code-key which generates the entire colorbar when it is executed:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.11}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            colorbar,
            colorbar/draw/.append code={%
                % the /.append code means that colorbar/draw is
                % executed as usual -- and we execute the following
                % code as well, which draws a _second_ colorbar on top
                % of it:
                \pgfplotsset{
                    colorbar sampled line={
                        samples at={0,0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8},
                        scatter,
                        scatter/use mapped color={draw=mapped color!50!black},
                        only marks,
                        mark=-, 
                        mark size=\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/colorbar/width}/2,
                        line width=2pt,
                    },
                    %
                    % do not typeset labels twice:
                    hide axis,
                    %
                    % colorbar sampled line overwrites (resets)
                    % colorbar/draw.
                    %
                    % Execute it to draw the result:
                    colorbar/draw,
                }%
            },%
        ]
        \addplot[contour prepared,contour/draw color=mapped color!50!black]
            table {
                2 2 0.8
                0.857143 2 0.6
                1 1 0.6
                2 0.857143 0.6
                2.5 1 0.6
                2.66667 2 0.6
                0.571429 2 0.4
                0.666667 1 0.4
                1 0.666667 0.4
                2 0.571429 0.4
                3 0.8 0.4
                0.285714 2 0.2
                0.333333 1 0.2
                1 0.333333 0.2
                2 0.285714 0.2
                3 0.4 0.2
            };
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The graphics layers could be better, but it appears to be ok.

---

*EDIT*

You asked for improvement regarding layered graphics. The good news is: my initial solution would work out of the box by adding `\pgfplotsset{set layers}` - this would automatically sort layers. Unfortunately, there seems to be a bug in pgfplots which means that layered graphics break colorbars :-(   I will take care of that bug.

That bug lead me to a workaround. This workaround relies on internal knowledge of the colorbar implementation: every (current) colorbar respects a key called `/pgfplots/colorbar addplot`. The purpose of that key is to visualize the colorbar as such, without its axis. If we customize that one, we can archieve the correct layering. Here is the solution:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.11}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            colorbar,
            colorbar style={%
                colorbar addplot/.add={}{%
                    \addplot[
                        samples at={0,0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8},
                        clip marker paths,
                        scatter,
                        point meta=y,
                        scatter/use mapped color={draw=mapped color!50!black},
                        only marks,
                        mark=-, 
                        mark size=\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/colorbar/width}/2,
                        line width=2pt,
                    ]
                        (0.5,x);
                },
            },
        ]
        \addplot[contour prepared,contour/draw color=mapped color!50!black]
            table {
                2 2 0.8
                0.857143 2 0.6
                1 1 0.6
                2 0.857143 0.6
                2.5 1 0.6
                2.66667 2 0.6
                0.571429 2 0.4
                0.666667 1 0.4
                1 0.666667 0.4
                2 0.571429 0.4
                3 0.8 0.4
                0.285714 2 0.2
                0.333333 1 0.2
                1 0.333333 0.2
                2 0.285714 0.2
                3 0.4 0.2
            };
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is great, thanks a lot - didn't know about `colorbar sampled line`.
As you mentioned, the layers aren't quite right - is there any way to place the axis lines above the markers or clip the markers of the second axis using the axis lines of the first?

Comment: Perfect, thanks!  I tried `set layers` but hadn't realised the output was caused by a bug.  Once again, I'm very impressed by how much pgfplots is capable of.  One final question: can it do my laundry and cooking for me?